# PHP-FPM for nginx on debian

Tags: php, nginx, debian, php-fpm, repository

What is the preferred/recommended way of installing php-fpm on debian for use with nginx? I read about a "php5-fpm" package everywhere, but it's not available in the official debian repos any more.

The PHP-FPM website (http://php-fpm.org/download/) says that fpm is now included with the php core. Is it enough to install "php5-common" then? Where are the config files, though?

Other people recommend to install the current version of php and php-fpm from dotdeb.org. The versions provided there are generally more up to date. But is it secure? Is this a good repo to use in a production environment?

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP5-FPM is being shipped with the core PHP project since June 2010, but has only granted the non-experimental status since the 5.4.0RC2 release less than a year ago.[<sup>1</sup>](http://php-fpm.org/) For Debian, it is available in Wheezy (now testing) and up[<sup>2</sup>](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php5-fpm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), as it hasn't made the Squeeze release. It might be available in the 'official' squeeze-backports some day, but that will still be PHP 5.3.x.

For now you'll have to stick with custom builds like the ones on [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org/2012/09/16/php-5-4-7-and-php-5-3-17/) if you need to run Debian Squeeze and don't want to compile it all yourself.

FYI, Ubuntu has already released three stable releases including PHP-FPM.[<sup>3</sup>](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php5-fpm)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So I think, I will use the dotdeb.org packages with priority based apt sources as described here: http://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing. Let me know if its a bad idea or if I could do anything else to ensure my setup is secure and production-ready.

Comment: I got everything working using apt-pinning. To help everybody else out, I posted my solution below as a separated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the first answer I used the packages from dotdeb.org. To prevent apt from installing all available packages from this repo generally, I used apt-pinning in /etc/apt/preferences as suggested in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/382101/129350).

My settings look like this:

**security.pref**

```
Pin: release l=Debian-Security
Pin-Priority: 1000
Package: *
```

**stable.pref**

```
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 990
Package: *
```

**dotdeb.pref**

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=packages.dotdeb.org
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-php5filter php-pear php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-dbg php5-dev php5-enchant php5-fpm php5-gd php5-gmp php5-imap php5-interbase php5-intl php5-ldap php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-odbc php5-pgsql php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-sybase php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5
Pin: release o=packages.dotdeb.org
Pin-Priority: 991
```

*(create your sources.list files accordingly as shown in the linked answer above.)*

With this setup the dotdeb packages never get installed **by default** (since security has still a higher priority) and all "non-php" (like nginx, redis, mysql, ..) packages aren't installed **at all**. (priority: 100)

To install your (wanted) php-packages run apt-get with **-t** to specify the repository to install from, e.g. like this:

```
apt-get install -t stable php5-fpm php5-common php5-cgi
```

*(remember that you have to include all dependencies in your install statement!)*

You can of course adjust this setup according to your situation. Hope this helps to get you on the right track.

Read more about apt-pinning [in this guide](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) and on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/apt_preferences).