# apt-get install -t testing appX VS apt-get install appX/testing

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I've been trying to understand the difference between these two commands and noticed that I get different results.

```
apt-get install -t testing appX
apt-get install appX/testing
```

**Background**

I setup my sources lists and pinning config as per https://serverfault.com/a/382101/132528

**Current outcomes**

```
root@home:/etc/apt# apt-cache policy i3
i3:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 4.2-2
Version table:
   4.8-1 0
    750 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
    750 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
    50 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
    50 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
   4.8-1~bpo70+1 0
    100 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
   4.2-2 0
    995 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
    995 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
    995 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

It chooses 4.2-2, when doing

```
apt-get install -t testing appX
```

And chooses 4.8 when doing

```
apt-get install appX/testing
```

**Debian handbook:**

-t targetRelease

> To tell apt-get to use a specific distribution when searching for upgraded packages, you need to use the -t or --target-release option, followed by the name of the distribution you want (for example: apt-get -t stable upgrade).

pkg/distribution

> If the file sources.list mentions several distributions, it is possible to give the version of the package to install. A specific version number can be requested with apt-get install package=version, but indicating its distribution of origin (Stable, Testing or Unstable) — with apt-get install package/distribution — is usually preferred.

**Question**

In both cases you specify the distribution you want, but the behaviour at hand is not consistent between the two cases?

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem, but I figured it out!!!

(I originally wanted to comment this on [the original answer](https://serverfault.com/a/382101/120130) because other people seem to be having this problem too, but I didn't have enough magic "reputation" points at the time for my opinion to be valuable, so here goes.)

It's a quirk of the values he chose for apt-pinning. When you run `apt-get install my_package`, apt chooses which source to install that package from based on whichever has the highest pinning priority.

Your overall system setting (Default Release) has a priority of 990.

Adding `-t unstable` to the apt-get command temporarily makes "unstable" the Default Release for that command.

He set up his Pinning Priority for "stable" to be ***995***. That means that no matter what, packages will always be installed from stable since its priority is even higher than the Default Release priority.

So the fix? Easy - just change the pin priority in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/security.pref` from 995 to 900.