# Puppet: how to install git package from Debian wheezy-backports?

Tags: debian, puppet, git, apt

I am using the Apt module (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) and have added an entry for the Debian wheezy backports repository:

```
apt::source { 'wheezy-backports':
    location    => 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian',
    release     => 'wheezy-backports',
    repos       => 'main',
    include_deb => true,
    include_src => true,
    notify      => Exec['apt-get-update'],
}
```

I can successfully install packages that are available in wheezy-backports but not in the default repository, so I think that the configuration itself is correct. Manually installing from backports using `apt-get install git -t wheezy-backports` works too.

But how do I force Puppet to retrieve a package from wheezy-backports instead of the default repository? Specifically, I want to install git-1.9.1-1 which is in wheezy backports but

```
package { "git": ensure => "1:1.9.1-1~bpo70+2", }
```

fails.

```
package { "git": ensure => "latest", }
```

will only install the latest version from the default repository but not the newer backport version.

Please advise how to force Puppet to retrieve a specific package from the wheezy-backports repository.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Debian backports documentation](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/), you need to manually specify the repository when you install via the CLI, because backported packages are pinned with a higher priority than default packages.

As per [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing), you will need to pin either the entire repository or individual packages to use backports.

With the Puppetlabs apt module, you can do this do this using the `apt::backports` class, which will both add the backports repository and drop a pin file:

```
class { 'apt::backports':
  location => 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian',
  release  => 'wheezy-backports',
  repos    => 'main',
  pin      => 500,
}
```

If you don't want to pin the entire repository, you can pin individual packages using `apt::pin` (the below is an example, you may need to tweak it):

```
apt::pin { 'backports_git':
  packages => 'git',
  priority => 500,
  release  => 'main',
}
```

More documentation is here: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt#pin-a-specific-release

Comment: To make it work I had to change `'main'` to the backports release (here `'wheezy-backports'`) in the `apt::pin` resource