# Is it possible to apt-pin two packages.sury.org repositories, which have no unique Label, Component, Origin, etc?

Tags: debian

This has taken me two separate multi-hour sessions to fully comprehend exactly how the `preferences.d` system works in apt.

On my local dev machine, I have *a lot* of different apt sources .. :

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
; ls
total 64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55 Jan 23 14:08 deb-backports.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 158 Mar  4 06:05 deb-experimental.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 164 Jan 23 14:23 deb-security.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 146 Mar  4 06:05 deb-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 148 Mar  4 06:05 deb-testing.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 150 Mar  4 06:05 deb-unstable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  42 Nov 30 22:35 dotdeb.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Nov 30 22:35 dotdeb.nginx-http2.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189 Oct  2 00:59 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  49 Feb  6 18:51 suryorg-nginx.list <-- here
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47 Feb  6 18:53 suryorg-php.list   <-- here
```

To save a bit of typing, I have all of the same preferences in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` as [this other ServerFault Question regarding apt pinning](https://serverfault.com/a/382101) ... (even though this is mostly irrelevant) .. as well as one additional custom pinning rule for `packages.sury.org`, which provides two separate repositories for both nginx and php. (this is not irrelevant...)

This results in this `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 950 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release n=jessie,c=main
     origin packages.sury.org
 950 https://packages.sury.org/nginx/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release n=jessie,c=main
     origin packages.sury.org
 900 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://packages.dotdeb.org/ jessie-nginx-http2/all amd64 Packages
     release o=packages.dotdeb.org,a=jessie-nginx-http2,n=jessie-nginx-http2,l=packages.dotdeb.org,c=all
     origin packages.dotdeb.org
 500 http://packages.dotdeb.org/ jessie/all amd64 Packages
     release o=packages.dotdeb.org,a=jessie,n=jessie,l=packages.dotdeb.org,c=all
     origin packages.dotdeb.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/contrib Translation-en
  50 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
     ... { snipped }
```

I was very confused on how to pin custom/third party apt repositories, such as dotdeb and sury.org, until I figured out how to use the `a=`, `n=`, `v=`, `c=`, `o=`, as well as "origin" vs "release" options for the Pin: line, my sury.org, as described in [apt_preferences man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html).  For example, doing a pin for dotdeb's multiple repositories is simple:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: * 
Pin: release a=jessie-nginx-http2 
Pin-Priority: -1
```

... with the "archive" line (`a=` bit) readily available via `apt-cache policy`.  (Note: I don't understand if *actually* doing that particular example above would make sense in many situations, just a contrived example).

Then, we get to sury.org:

```
 950 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release n=jessie,c=main
     origin packages.sury.org
 950 https://packages.sury.org/nginx/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release n=jessie,c=main
     origin packages.sury.org
```

As you can see, the only thing specified here is the codename part (`n=jessie`) and no unique archive name, component, or label.

I tried to use the `origin` method, e.x.

```
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.sury.org
Pin-Priority: 950
```

And you can see above in the `apt-cache policy` output, this *does* work.  However, there is no way to narrow it down to the individual `/nginx/` or `/php/` repository directory parts as far as I can tell.  By putting the directory/path part in the "`Pin:`" line, it stops matching the rule.  That is, ...

```
...
Pin: origin packages.sury.org/nginx/
```

Does not work as expected.  Is there any workaround for this?  Or is this simply a shortcoming of the sury.org maintainer (which no offense to them, they do a great job, .. this is just a bit of an edge case, and I am also just honestly curious)

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Filtering it to specific packages might work: e.g. `Package: *nginx*`