# Get Latest OS Variant dictionary definitions for KVM

Tags: debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, windows-server-2016

I have a Debian 9.4 host running KVM.

I need to deploy a `Windows Server 2016` guest. However, the current osinfo definitions only cover up to `Windows Server 2012 R2`.

I am aware that the definitions come from the package [libosinfo-1.0-0](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libosinfo-1.0-0) and I have checked that all packages are up to date with the Debian stable.

1. Is there a timetable for when the Debian stable will get the `win2k16` definition?
2. Will getting the latest `libosinfo` [from source](https://libosinfo.org/download/) cause conflicts or compatibility problems with the other debian packages? Does anyone have any experience of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package that actually contains the OS definitions is [`osinfo-db`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=osinfo-db). The current version, 20180628, is in buster, but not in stretch. It *should* be safe to [pull this package in from testing](https://serverfault.com/q/22414/126632). But this post has no warranty; if it breaks you get to keep both pieces.