# How to upgrade a package in Debian 8?

Tags: debian, upgrade, packages

I'm using a docker image that comes with Debian 8 (jessie). I'm trying to upgrade curl package to the latest (7.58) from 7.38.

Running `apt-cache showpkg curl` shows that 7.38 is the latest version, but curl is at 7.58 (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.2/basicnet/curl.html)

I also checked Debian package website and it it looks like 7.38 is the latest. https://packages.debian.org/jessie/curl

Is there a way to upgrade curl 7.38 on my system to the latest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal as Debian 8 (jessie) is currently the *oldstable* [release](https://www.debian.org/releases/). If you search for [Package curl](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=curl) you'll notice that the *stable* version currently has curl 7.52, while *testing* & *unstable* are already on version 7.62.

Old Debian releases won't have new feature updates, but receives security updated for a rather long [LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) period. Therefore, having an older version doesn't mean you are at risk. Consider upgrading only if you actually need some new features.

> Is there a way to upgrade curl 7.38 on my system to the latest?

- It's possible to [run Debian stable but install some packages from testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing/22418#22418), but mixing stable and testing may cause dependency conflicts, and mixing oldstable and testing is probably even more problematic.
- You can always compile, build and [install curl from source](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html). (No automatic updates, though.)

Comment: Thank you so much. It sounds like I will be upgrading my Debian today :)